# Making audio player work in swift (xcode 7.1.1)?

Tags: ios, audio, swift2

Im having an issue with an audio player I'm trying to put together using swift, built for use in a game application. The code below is what i have. I already have all the mp3 files in separate child groups within my main sounds folder, yet I cannot understand why the NSURL cannot be identified.

import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

```
var backgroundMusicPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        }
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    var BGMusicURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("BGMusicURL", withExtension: "mp3")
    backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL, error: nil)
    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
}
```

if anyone could help me update my code that would be great, (I'm a beginner with swift as I'm sure you can tell)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Old answer:
Try using AVPlayer instead of AVAudioPlayer

**Edit/new answer**: 
Try to add ! at the end of var URLForResource, that's how you force unwrapping so maybe it will work

Like this

```
var BGMusicURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("BGMusicURL", withExtension: "mp3")!
```

Comment: Thanks Petar for your response!
Ive just tried that and it just doesnt seem to be having any of it. It says that URLForResource is not unwrapped, and that it cannot invoke initialiser for AVPlayer.
Im sure I'll figure it out eventually

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I dont really know what to do!

Comment: @SamuelJones Have you tried edit/new answer solution?